# remove filename between specific character

Tags: powershell

I need Help with powershell

I need to remove the number 10 between 2nd and 3rd minus sign '-'
ABCDE-2020-10-20.txt
HIJKL-2020-10-20.txt
MNOPQ-2020-10-20.txt
RSTUV-2020-10-20.txt

so far this is what I got for renaming logic but I'm having problem getting the filename

```
foreach ($s in $files) {
 $newString = $s-replace "-", ""
 $count = $s.Length - $newString.Length
 
 if ($count -ge 3) {
     $s01=$s.indexof("-",0)
     $s02=$s.indexof("-",$s.indexof("-",0)+1)
     $s.substring(0,$s01) + $s.substring($s02)
 }
}
```

`$files = (Get-ChildItem -path $folder -recurse -File).FullName`

.fullname this will get me full path but my folder name contain - too,
.name will get me only file name but is there anyway to rename with just the filename ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, its not clear if your overall goal is removing the date or just the `-10`, but here is a few ideas.

```
$string -replace '\-\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}'
```

`ABCDE.txt`

```
$string -replace '(\-\d\d\W)','-'
```

`ABCDE-2020-20.txt`

```
$string -replace '(\-\d\d\b)'
```

`ABCDE-2020.txt`